# error configuración xampp sql server windows server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xampp

Estoy configurando el php.ini de xampp para trabajar con conexiones a sql server.  Primero me daba un error de que no encontraba la php7.dll.  La descargué y guardé en la carpeta correspondiente.  Pero ahora surge otro error:

no se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento _zval_ptr_dtor en la biblioteca de vìnculos dinàmicos php7ts.dll

Intentè lo poco que encontré en algunos post, incluso instalando el Visual C++ Redistributable para la versiòn correspondiente de php que se instaló y aún sigue sin funcionar.

Alguna idea de la solución?

Comment: ¿Los dll de SQL Server que tienes concuerdan con tu versión de PHP?

Comment: Mil gracias @JosueArriola verifiqué las versiones y esa era el problema, tenìa las 7 en lugar de la 7.4

Comment: @Virginia donde puedo encontrar esas versiones especificas? 7.4.11

Comment: @Riddick exactamente no tengo la url, pero puedes googlear librerías .dll y el nombre de la que necesitas

Comment: @Virginia pude resolver el tema, gracias

Comment: como solventaste el problema??... instalé las dll para la version 7.4 de php, pero el error de que no se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento me sigue apareciendo, tengo windows 10 y tambien instale el VC++ redestributable.